# iPod Artwork Size issue in CCSprite?

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, ipod, ccsprite, artwork

So I have a CCSprite in one of the scenes in my app. I load an image from a sprite sheet into it by doing initWithSpriteFrameName. Then later on, when the user plays a song from their iPod library I attempt to do this:

(albumArtwork is a CCSprite)

```
MPMediaItemArtwork *itemArtwork = [musicPlayer.nowPlayingItem valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyArtwork];
UIImage *artworkImage = [itemArtwork imageWithSize:CGSizeMake(albumArtwork.boundingBox.size.width, albumArtwork.boundingBox.size.height)];
CCTexture2D *tex = [[CCTextureCache sharedTextureCache] addCGImage:resizedArtworkImage.CGImage forKey:@"albumArtwork"];
[albumArtwork setTexture:tex];
```

However, the image must be huge because the CCSprite itself only shows 1/4 of the album artwork. I have tried to lower the size of the image and that didn't help. Does anyone know why this is happening?

Thanks!

Comment: Give a try : set [albumArtwork setTextureRect:newResizedRect]; //After  setTexture line.

Comment: Nope didn't work. It seems like the artwork image is zoomed in for some unknown reason. I think this is just an issue with CCSprite's so maybe I should just try using a UIButton.

Comment: What I ended up just doing is creating another CCSprite especially for the artwork image and that worked. No idea why this weird bug is occurring though for one sprite.